# How to filter a list of floats based on their elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to programming.

Basically in a list of floats, I want my program to print every one that starts with either '1' or '-1'. This is what I have so far.

```
def oneminus(L):  
    for i in range(len(L)):  
        if L[i][0]=='1':  
            print(L[i])  
        elif L[i][0]=='-' and L[i][1]=='1':  
            print(L[i])
```

When I run the program however I get the error "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" So I'm assuming the issue is due to the fact the list contains floats.

Comment: And an ugly one liner. :-) `for x in filter(lambda x:str(x).strip('-').startswith('1'), L): print(x)`

Comment: @pasztor If you need a lambda for filter, you're better off just using a list comprehension.

Comment: @Antimony This is indeed equivalent and looks much nicer, thank you. `for x in (f for f in L if str(x).strip('-').startswith('1')): print(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're treating the elements as strings, not floats. Unlike PHP and Javascript, Python doesn't have implicit type coercion. If you want to get the string representation, you have to convert it explicitly using `str` or `repr`.

What you want is something like

```
def oneminus(L): 
    for x in L:
        if str(x).startswith('1') or str(x).startswith('-1'):
            print(x)
```

You could make it shorter by taking advantage of `str.strip`.

```
def oneminus(L): 
    for x in L:
        if str(x).strip('-').startswith('1'):
            print(x)
```

Also note that you can iterate over a list directly.

Comment: is there a way to do it without ".startswith" or ".strip"? I tried str(L[i][0])=='1' but i still get the same error

Comment: @NavesinkBanks `str(L[i])[0]=='1'`